# how to set environment variables in ubuntu to access private gems in gemfile in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

i have a `private gem` in my `gemfile` in my rails app

```
git: "https://#{ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN']}:x-oauth-xyz@github.com/abc/cdf.git"
```

i know the GITHUB_TOKEN so i tried accessing like this.

```
git: "https://xyztoken:x-oauth-xyz@github.com/abc/cdf.git"
```

but this way it's not working.

so i want to create a `operating system` level `environment variable` for this.

i opened the `.bashrc` file using `vim editor`. but now i dont know how to set it up, so that it can pick from this file.

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN=xyztoken
```